# Assign a category to a product without repeating

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, dense-rank

I have a function that produces a table like below. The sequence is important here.
I want each product to be assigned to a separate category, but if there is a change over time, eg Product D to Product C (row 11) , then another category should be created. The result I want to get is in the Result column.

| Order | Number | Product | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 106893 | Product A | 1 |
| 2 | 108468 | Product B | 2 |
| 3 | 108468 | Product B | 2 |
| 4 | 107011 | Product C | 3 |
| 5 | 107011 | Product C | 3 |
| 6 | 107011 | Product C | 3 |
| 7 | 107011 | Product D | 4 |
| 8 | 107011 | Product D | 4 |
| 9 | 107011 | Product D | 4 |
| 10 | 107011 | Product D | 4 |
| 11 | 107011 | Product C | 5 |
| 12 | 107011 | Product E | 6 |
| 13 | 107011 | Product E | 6 |

I tried to do it with rank() but in line 11 it again throws me a result of 3 instead of 5.

Theoretically, I did it with CTE, but it takes a long time to calculate on a small sample. There must be a simpler and faster way.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()` to see where there is a switch.  Then use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_product = product then 0 else 1 end) over (order by order)
from (select t.*,
             lag(product) over (order by order) as prev_product
      from t
     ) t;
```

`order` is, of course, a SQL keyword.  It is a bad name for a column and may need to be escaped if that is the actual name.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
This is what I was looking for
And this unfortunate ORDER name is just here in the example, it is fine on production :)